# Lombok issues compilating my java project

Tags: java, maven, compilation, lombok

I'm trying to compile a java file but I get a lombok error, I searched for a solution and apparenly I got to update lombok.

I searched for how to update it on IntelliJ but I didn't find anything.

Can someone please help me ?

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9XRm.png)

Unable to make field private com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$DiscoveredProcessors com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoveredProcs accessible: module jdk.compiler does not "opens com.sun.tools.javac.processing" to unnamed module @265bd546

Comment: Ctrl-Shift-A -> "plugins" -> find the Lombok plugin -> Update